# Why am i getting NSubstitute.Exceptions.RedundantArgumentMatcherException intermittently?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, nsubstitute

I am having trouble with NSubstitute when I am running a suite of tests. I intermittently receives the NSubstitute.Exceptions.RedundantArgumentMatcherException: Some argument specifications (e.g. Arg.Is, Arg.Any) were left over after the last call.

As this particular suite only contains the below two unit tests I cannot see i what way I can have these troubles.

```
public class MyResolverTests
{
    private readonly MyResolver _sut;
    private readonly IObjectClient _objectClientMock;

    public MyResolverTests()
    {
        _objectClientMock = Substitute.For<IObjectClient>();
        _sut = new MyResolver(_objectClientMock);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void IsApplicable_when_something_then_return_true()
    {
        //Arrange
        var myEnum = MyEnum.Value1;

        //Act
        var result = _sut.IsApplicable(myEnum);

        //Assert
        Assert.True(result);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetSomething_then_return_myobject()
    {
        //Arrange
        _objectClientMock
            .GetAsync<MyObject>(Arg.Any<Guid>(), Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<bool>(),
                Arg.Any<bool>()).Returns(new MyObject()));

        //Act
        var result = await _sut.GetRepresentation(Guid.NewGuid());

        //Assert
        Assert.IsType<MyObject>(result);
    }
}
```

Have I misunderstood the way it should be used? Is there an incorrect implementation above?  From that we have been using MOQ without these troubles to this intermittent problem is disturbing.

Comment: Which version of NSubstitute are you using ?

Comment: We are using 5.1.0

Comment: are you sure that you are subbing the right method. Does your GetAsync<MyObject> gets called in GetRepresentation ?

Comment: Yes it is. Though i fiiinally found the issue and it was just as the exceptions were saying. It was all about Arg.Any on concrete class. But there was too much code to go through and it took nearly two full days. But now it is all working